# Precise Error Term in Chebotarev's Theorem

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a Galois Number Field with Galois group $G$ and discriminant $\Delta_K$.  Chebotarev's theorem states that the number of (unramified) rational primes with Frobenius conjugacy class in a set of conjugacy classes $D \subseteq G$ is $\pi_D(x) \sim \frac{|D|}{|G|} \pi(x)$, where $\pi(x)$ is the rational prime counting function.  Serre proved assuming GRH that 
\begin{equation*}
|\pi_D(x) - \frac{|D|}{|G|} \text{Li}(x)| \ll x^{\frac{1}{2}}|D|(\log x+ \log |G| + \log \Delta_K).
\end{equation*}
What is currently the best unconditional estimate on the error term?

Comment: Does this help you? http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~ono/publications-cv/pdfs/062.pdf

Comment: This is great, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The OP could be helped with this paper about of Balog and Ono.

http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~ono/publications-cv/pdfs/062.pdf